# bash while loop not printing what is expected

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying this simple `while` loop in bash.

My text file

```
# cat test.txt
line1:21
line2:25
line5:27
These are all on new line
```

My Script

```
# cat test1.sh
while read line
do
        awk -F":" '{print $2}'
done < test.txt
```

Output

```
# ./test1.sh
25
27
```

The output isn't printing the first line `$2` value. Could anyone please help me understand this case?

Comment: See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need that loop:

```
$ awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' test.txt
21
25
27
```

`awk` will process the input line by line.

---

With your loop, the `read` will get the first line of the file, which is lost since it's not used/outputted.  The `awk` will then take over the standard input of the loop and read the other two lines in the file (so the loop will only ever do one single iteration).

Your loop, annotated:

```
while read line                # first line read ($line never used)
do
    awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }'  # reads from standard input, which will
                               # contain the rest of the test.txt file
done <test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I able to fix your code by adding `echo`. Reason for this have described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779351/5625691), question why it's printing other two values.

```
while read line;
do
        echo "$line" | awk -F":" '{print $2}'
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS=":" read z x; do 
  echo $x; 
done<test.txt
```

or

```
sed "s/^.*://g" test.txt
```